# How To display data from API in drupal page or in View?

Tags: drupal-7

How to call API in drupal and display data from that API in to page or create drupal view of that API data? I want to display data that is coming from API in drupal page or i want to create view of data that is coming from API. If anyone knows this, please share in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a drupal module for webservices or api.
In hook menu, you can provide the url and function info like this

```
$items['api/v1.0/projectListings'] = array(
    'title' => t('Project Listings'),
    'description' => t('Project listings '),
    'page callback' => 'project_listings',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

On call back function you can query your needs

```
function project_listings(){
    //get the data eg: $data
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Using hook menu url you can  retrive the data and use in the page you want by decoding the received JSON data

Comment: But how to display this using drupal services module

Comment: Oops, I like to create my own web services rather that using modules for services. Though heres a nice article by Steve Burge on drupal webservices. Hope it helps [drupal web services overview](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/services/)